# How to write a wrapper cookooks in chef for the local cookbooks and not dependent on the chef community chef cookbooks?

Tags: chef-infra, wrapper, devops, knife

I have two base chef cookbooks which are written from scratch, one cookbook is dependent on the other. Both the cookbooks are not dependent on community cookbooks. So, I was asked to create a wrapper cookbook with the 2 base chef cookbooks

For example:
I have two cookbooks "test-a" and "test-b" and both of them are available on the chef server hosted On-premises and are not dependent on the community cookbooks.

Ask is to create a wrapper cookbook "test" with the above cookbooks "test-a" and "test-b". so that, they can do a knife bootstrap/role/run_list.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utilize the `run_list` in the [role](https://docs.chef.io/roles.html#role-formats) object. in your case, it should be something like:

```
$ cat roles/test.json
{
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[test-a]",
    "recipe[test-b]"
  ]
}
```

another method, is to create another a cookbook named `test` and utilize the [`include_recipe`](https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html#include-recipes), and it should be something like:

```
$ cat test/recipes/default.rb
include_recipe 'test-a'
include_recipe 'test-b'

$ cat test/metadata.rb
depends 'test-a'
depends 'test-b'
```

if you have attributes which you would like to override, then do it in the `test` wrapper cookbook. for instance, if the `test-a` cookbook has an attribute such as `node.default[:foo] = 'baz'`, then you can override it as follows

```
$ cat test/attributes/default.rb
node.default[:foo] = 'spam'
```

consider reading [Writing Wrapper Cookbooks](https://blog.chef.io/2017/02/14/writing-wrapper-cookbook/) and [Doing Wrapper Cookbooks Right](https://blog.chef.io/2013/12/03/doing-wrapper-cookbooks-right/) on chef blog

Comment: Thanks for the information. So how about passing overrride attributes to the wrapper cookbook.

Comment: @Jeetu: following your question, i've updated my answer. i hope it solves your issue. if it does, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)